# Any refreshable groovy classloader implement?

Tags: groovy, classloader

I am looking for a refreshable groovy classloader,I want to let groovy file change on fly,I know
`GroovyScriptEngine` do the thing,but if I have `AClass.groovy` and `BClass.groovy`, and I write in `AClass`:

```
 Class pageClass = ClassUtils.forName("BClass", this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

and auto reloading BClass is not work when `BClass.groovy` is not work.

I think the best solution is need a refreshable ClassLoader,but I can not find the exisiting implemention.

And I am not using spring-groovy and grails,I want a independent implemention.

Thanks

Comment: "BClass is not work when BClass.groovy is not work" means BClass cannot be loaded if BClass.groovy does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want I'm sure but if you want to do something ONLY with Groovy (no Spring or Grails) that allows you to change stuff and not have to restart your application, you might look at doing some initial work with Groovlets -> http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets

This is only for servlet container work and probably won't be extremely useful as your application gets large but it would allow you to initially change things frequently and simply refresh with a call to the Groovlet.

If you did consider using Spring, scripted beans are 'refreshable' and you can implement that yourself using Java's dynamic language support but I'd suggest simply letting Spring do it for you.